# php/mysql - get unique order number sequentiel

Tags: php, mysql

i want to get a unique order number for my script.
by now i have a mysql table that stores a field 'next_order_number'.
if i need a number i read the table, grab the field an increment it an write back to table.

now i get sometimes the problem, that i get the numbers two times - the same number twicew !
This happens if the script runs two times nearly at the same time.

What could be the best way to handle this ?
The numbers should be sequentiel - no random-numbers !

thanks so far - jogi

Comment: I don't know how you table looks like or its main purpose to manually increment number, but wouldn't it be better, if that number will use `AUTO_INCREMENT` by database itself?

Comment: Try looking for "MySQL Sequence Generator"

Comment: sure but i have to write the order in a database and in a csv-file.

Comment: After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @debute the `AUTO_INCREMENT` would probably be the best option, although you could use the `MAX()` functionality... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column.html

Comment: ok but i need the incremented value for my csv file. how can i read it if the key is auto-incremented ?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: the point im struggling is last_insert_id(). if two user insert at the same time and call last_insert_id at the same time the value could be wrong ?

Comment: ok isee the last_insert_id is connection specific - so i understand --- thanks !!!!!!!!!!!!!